# Asymptote only outputs EPS even when set to PDF

Tags: miktex, asymptote

Attempting to configure Asymptote independently before using it with Latex. Asymptote only outputs EPS files even with `settings.outformat="pdf"`. What is missing here?

OS: Windows 10,
IDE: Visual Studio Code, Asymptote: version 2.83

Installed packagaes:

```
 choco install asymptote
 choco install miktex
 choco install ghostscript
 choco install sumatrapdf
 choco install imagemagick
```

%USERPROFILE%\config.asy:

```
import settings;
outformat="pdf";
pdfviewer="cmd";
htmlviewer="cmd";
psviewer="cmd";
display="cmd";
animate="cmd";
gs="cmd";
libgs="";
```

Simple program `test.asy` that draws two lines:

```
unitsize(1cm);
draw((-.1,0) -- (2,0));
draw((0,-.1) -- (0,2));
```

Command:
`asy -V -f pdf test`

Verbose command output `asy -V -vvv -f pdf test`:

```
PS C:\Users\user1\documents\asymptote> asy -V -vvv -f pdf test
Using configuration directory C:/Users/user1\.asy     
Loading config.asy from C:/Users/user1\.asy/config.asy
Using history C:/Users/user1\.asy/history
Welcome to Asymptote version 2.83
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/user1/documents/asymptote
Processing test
Loading plain from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain.asy
Including plain_constants from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_constants.asy
Loading version from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/version.asy
Including plain_strings from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_strings.asy
Including plain_pens from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_pens.asy
Including plain_paths from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_paths.asy
Including plain_filldraw from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_filldraw.asy
Including plain_margins from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_margins.asy
Including plain_picture from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_picture.asy
Loading plain_scaling from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_scaling.asy
Loading simplex from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/simplex.asy
Loading plain_bounds from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_bounds.asy
Including plain_scaling from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_scaling.asy
Including plain_prethree from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_prethree.asy
Including plain_Label from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_Label.asy
Including plain_arcs from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_arcs.asy
Including plain_boxes from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_boxes.asy
Including plain_shipout from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_shipout.asy
Including plain_markers from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_markers.asy
Including plain_arrows from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_arrows.asy
Including plain_debugger from C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_debugger.asy
Loading test from test.asy
cmd -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -P -dSAFER -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dEPSCrop -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dEncodeColorImages=true -dEncodeGrayImages=true -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -g612x792 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=60.0276 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=60.0276 -sOutputFile=test.pdf -c .setsafe -f test_.eps
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1526]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: In your configuration file you specify `gs="cmd"`, which means that you tell Asymtote that Gostscript (the program that converts eps to pdf) is `cmd.exe`, i.e., the Windows Command Prompt. Try `gs="gs"` instead, or leave the whole line out, then presumably a default is used that should point to a system-installed Ghostscript.

Comment: As an aside: all the other entries with `cmd` are incorrect as well, the command prompt is not a pdf/html/ps viewer or a display or animation program.

Comment: @Marijn okay thank you. Yes completely removing the lines containing "cmd" works.